# SharePoint 2007 : Designer Workflow getting restarted after 20-30 mins ( only few instances in the library)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a custom SharePoint Designer approval workflow which is restarting (only for few instances in document library) after 20-30 mins, thereby failing the workflow as i am checking few conditions. We have tested this workflow and it runs absolutely fine for most of the instances. Someone told me that it may be due to server load and workflow history items exceeding 2000 items . So i made sure the workflow history items are less than 500. But it still re-starts. The number of workflow instances in the library is about 150. How can i debug to find the exact cause for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By any chance do you have a lot of workflows running in the farm. Can you check that? If yes, then you will have to increase your workflow throttling.

Excerpt from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd441390%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

The workflow throttle setting controls how many workflows can be processing at any one time on the entire server farm. This setting does not control how many workflows can be "In Progress" concurrently, but rather how many can be actively using the processor. When this number is exceeded, workflow instances that are started and events that wake up dehydrated workflows are queued for later processing. The default value is 15. This setting is per farm, so the number of front-end Web servers is irrelevant.